# Select elements with same attribute value

Tags: css

Is there any way to select elements with same attribute value which I don't exactly have access to? I imagine doing it in way like this:

`.first[attribute=.second[attribute]]`

I want to use ONLY pure CSS.

Comment: do you want to compare attribute values of two elements?

Comment: @Geeky Exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, there is no way to achieve this using css

however, if you need to do something like this you should consider changing your markup (ex. using additional classes) - css is not a programming language

Answer (score 1):

CSS cannot do that. For comparing two elements you need to have access to DOM.

We cannot achieve this through css but this can be done by JavaScript:

```js
window.onload=function(){
   var attr = 'elementValue',
       elements=document.querySelectorAll('.first, .second');

   console.log(
       elements[0].getAttribute(attr) ===
       elements[1].getAttribute(attr)
   );
}
```

```html
<div class="first" elementValue="1">hello</div>
<div class="second" elementValue="1">hello</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That is exactly the type of answer I was expecting. I know a way how to provide this with JS, but I wanted to know only CSS solution. Unfortunately, there isn't any. Thumbs up though!